# make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

Tags: java, apache

One of the suggested solutions is to note the PID running on port 80 (netstat -ano), kill it and start Apache and this has solved problem for many others. But for me Apache itself is running on port 80 and when I start the service I get socket not available error.
I tried changing the port to 8080 or other but no luck. Please suggest me where I am going wrong?

Exact Error Msg:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin>httpd.exe
>   (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
>   is normally permitted.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down

Unable to open logs

Comment: Apache is an application and your java is another application. that mean is both are running at same time they cant use the same port other than 8080. so change your app to use any other port if you need it to run while apache is running choose lets say 8915 as that is random port . and if that didnt work type the error you get here

Comment: I changed the port  to "Listen 8915" on httpd.conf and when I started the service I got the same error with different port.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin>httpd.exe -k sta
rt
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
is normally permitted.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8915
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

Answer (score -5):

There is no such address as 0.0.0.0; if you are trying to bind to an Apache port on the local host, use 127.0.0.1, please.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` binds to all interfaces.

Comment: This is ironic coming from someone who works at a network security laboratory.